# If row meets criteria, then TRUE else FALSE in R

Tags: r

I have nested data that looks like this:

```
ID  Date Behavior
1   1    FALSE
1   2    FALSE
1   3    TRUE
2   3    FALSE
2   5    FALSE
2   6    TRUE
2   7    FALSE
3   1    FALSE
3   2    TRUE
```

I'd like to create a column called `counter` in which for each unique `ID` the counter adds one to the next row until the `Behavior` = `TRUE`

I am expecting this result:

```
ID  Date Behavior counter
1   1    FALSE    1
1   2    FALSE    2
1   3    TRUE     3
2   3    FALSE    1
2   5    FALSE    2
2   6    TRUE     3
2   7    FALSE    
3   1    FALSE    1
3   2    TRUE     2
```

Ultimately, I would like to pull the minimum `counter` in which the observation occurs for each unique ID. However, I'm having trouble developing a solution for this current `counter` issue.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd like to create a counter within each array of unique `ID`s and from there, ultimately pull the row level info - the question is how long on average does it take to reach a `TRUE`...

Comment: You could do `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, counter := c(seq_len(which(Behavior)), rep(NA, .N - which(Behavior))), ID]` but I would go with @NPEs solution

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to create a counter within each array of unique `ID`s and from there, ultimately pull the row level info - the question is how long on average does it take to reach a `TRUE`

I sense there might an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here. You can answer your latter question directly, like so:

```
> library(plyr)
> mean(daply(d, .(ID), function(grp)min(which(grp$Behavior))))
[1] 2.666667
```

(where `d` is your data frame.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr solution that finds the row number for each TRUE in each ID:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- yourdataframe %>%
           group_by(ID) %>%
           summarise(
             ftrue = which(Behavior))
```

Comment: This solution would only work if each `ID` had one occurrence of `TRUE` - after which, you receive a `expecting a single value` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
do.call(rbind, by(df, list(df$ID), function(x) {n = nrow(x); data.frame(x, Counter = c(1:(m<-which(x$Behavior)), rep(NA, n-m)))}))

     ID  Date Behavior Counter
1.1  1    1    FALSE       1
1.2  1    2    FALSE       2
1.3  1    3     TRUE       3
2.4  2    3    FALSE       1
2.5  2    5    FALSE       2
2.6  2    6     TRUE       3
2.7  2    7    FALSE      NA
3.8  3    1    FALSE       1
3.9  3    2     TRUE       2

df = read.table(text = "ID  Date Behavior
                1   1    FALSE
                1   2    FALSE
                1   3    TRUE
                2   3    FALSE
                2   5    FALSE
                2   6    TRUE
                2   7    FALSE
                3   1    FALSE
                3   2    TRUE", header = T)
```

Comment: this is what I want to do - however I'm getting an `invalid 'times' argument` error. Any common suspects to such an error?

Comment: I can't replicate the error, but I'm guessing it is referring to the `times` argument in `rep.